# el boton buscar no me funciona en laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

En el controlador tengo este codigo que basicamente recoge el name del campo y luego filtra la busqueda

```
  /**
 * Funcion que retorna la vista de especialidades
 * @return void vincula con la vista de especialidades
 */
public function index(Request $request){
    // vamos a inyectar los datos en esta vista
    //$pacientes = Contacto::all();

    $search =  $request->input('buscarPor');
    if($search!=""){
        $listaPacientes = Contacto::where(function ($query) use ($search){
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        });


    }
    else{
        $listaPacientes = Contacto::paginate(2);
    }
    return View('pacientes.index')->with('pacientes',$listaPacientes);
    //
```

en el inde.blade tengo esta parte del codigo, pero creo que el error esta en la ruta que viene del controlador

```
@extends('layouts.panel')

@section('content')
  <div class="card shadow">
    <div class="card-header border-0">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col">
          <h3 class="mb-0">Pacientes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-right">
          <a href="{{url('/pacientes/crear')}}" class="btn btn-big btn-primary">Nueva paciente</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-12">
        <form action="" class="d-flex">
            <div class="form-row col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Texto a buscar" name="buscarPor">{{-- value="{{$valorBuscado}}"> --}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        @if (session('notificaciones'))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                {{session('notificaciones')}}
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <!-- Projects table -->
      <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr class=>
            <th scope="col">Id paciente</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre del paciente</th>
            <th scope="col">Direccion del paciente</th>
            <th scope="col">Telefono del paciente</th>
            <th scope="col">Movil del paciente</th>
            <th scope="col">Email del paciente</th>
            <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($pacientes as $datosEspecialidades)
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">
                {{$datosEspecialidades->id}}
              </th>
            <th>
              {{$datosEspecialidades->name}}
            </th>
            <td>
                {{$datosEspecialidades->direccion}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$datosEspecialidades->telefono}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{$datosEspecialidades->movil}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{$datosEspecialidades->email}}
              </td>
             <td>
                <form action="{{url('/pacientes/'.$datosEspecialidades->id)}}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <a href="{{url('/pacientes/'.$datosEspecialidades->id.'/editar')}}" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Editar</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>

          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{-- <div class="btn-group mt-4 " role="group">
    {{ $pacientes->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')}}
  </div> --}}
```

@endsection

Y en el archivo de configuración de la rutas en el cual si esta bien enlazado

```
Route::get('/pacientes/buscar',[ContactoController::class, 'search']);
```

Entonces no entiendo porque no me busca, estoy bastante perdido, porque quiero una búsqueda simple y no entiendo como se hace eh mirado en diferentes post y videos y no me hace la búsqueda, ahora mismo cuando pulso en el botón buscar no aparece nada

Comment: Revisa tu form, le hace falta el action, por eso no hace nada.

Comment: Ya lo corregi, tampoco me aparece nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Añade un name, para no usar la ruta (opcional)
- cambie de get a any asi permite tanto get como post

```
Route::any('/pacientes/buscar',[ContactoController::class, 'search'])->name('pacientes.search');
```

- Al formulario añade el **action** que puede ser la ruta
  (/pacientes/buscar) o el name (pacientes.search)
- Añade method="POST"
- Añade @csrf (asi no te da el error 419)

```
   <form action="{{ route('pacientes.search') }}" method="POST" class="d-flex">
 @csrf
            <div class="form-row col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Texto a buscar" name="buscarPor">{{-- value="{{$valorBuscado}}"> --}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">
            </div>
        </form>
```

- Y Cambiaria el return a

> return view('pacientes.index')->compact('listaPacientes');

```php
public function index(Request $request){
    // vamos a inyectar los datos en esta vista
    //$pacientes = Contacto::all();

    $search =  $request->input('buscarPor');
    if($search!=""){
        $listaPacientes = Contacto::where(function ($query) use ($search){
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        });


    }
    else{
        $listaPacientes = Contacto::paginate(2);
    }
    
    return view('pacientes.index')->compact('listaPacientes');
}
```

Comment: muchas graciass